# Can't use {{> loginButtons}} with Meteor and Ionic

Tags: javascript, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

I wanna let my users to login/signing up in my Meteor/Ionic app. I thought it would be easy as I use simple {{> loginButtons}}, but it gives me an error `Uncaught Error: No such template: loginButtons` in console. My code is

```
<div class="bar bar-footer">
<button class="button button-clear">{{> loginButtons}}</button>
<div class="title">Start using!</div>
<button class="button button-clear">{{> loginButtons}}</button>
```

Of course I have all the neccessary packages installed (such as `meteoric:ionic` and packages for auth through social networks). 
So how can I do this feature anyway (I'm kinda new to all this stuff)? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Pardon me if you did, but have you installed the `accounts-ui` package? It's the one containing the `loginButtons` template. (well, `accounts-ui-unstyled` is, but it's included in `accounts-ui`)

Comment: Shame on me, I really forgot about it. Gotta pay more attention to really basic things next time. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some help, I figured out what's the problem. I forget to add `accounts-ui` package. After this everything worked really fine.